# How do I convert a float Number to a whole Number using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, converters

I'd like to convert a float to a whole number in jquery. Actually, I want to store the integer value in a variable from a float type vlue like 10.44 to 10 and I want to convert it only using jquery.

Comment: `Math.floor(10.44)` will return `10`

Comment: I want to use jquery. @vasilenicusor

Comment: jQuery has no number conversion functions of its own.  jQuery is javascript so you use the Javascript Math library to do this.